# Could the question tags please be added to the review queue evaluation page?

Tags: feature-request, tags, first-answers

On, at least, the First Answers Review Queue page on Stack Overflow it would be helpful if the tags on the question were also visible on the review page. I believe they would provide useful context in performing the review. In reviewing answers I have found myself clicking into the question just to see the question tags.

Over the course of using Stack Overflow, I have witnessed "bad" questions where sometimes the tags given to the question by the asker are the only way to be able to interpret what they are asking.

For example, adding a [bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bootstrap) tag to a question about JavaScript. An answer for Bootstrap, an answer for Angular, and an answer for React are going to be different. Part of the evaluation of an answer to a question like that, assuming the reviewer has knowledge relevant to reviewing an answer for specific content, could take that into account when providing feedback to the answerer.

Comment: By "*clicking into the question just to see the question tags*", did you mean clicking the title to see the whole Q&A thread, or the "Question" tab inside the review?

Comment: Re *"..."bad" questions where sometimes the tags given to the question by the asker are the only way to be able to interpret what they are asking."*: Yes, the minimum effort attitude will produce text like that. I don't believe for one second it is a matter of skillz.

Comment: @AndrewT. Yes, I clicked in to see the whole Q&A thread. I knew the question would show its tags, if there were any.